# Globe on my QGIS doesn't work

Tags: qgis, error, globe

OS : osx 10.9.2

- I just operated a clean osx installation.
  Globe have never worked since I started to learn QGIS.
  When I tried globe, it terminated QGIS then a message(see below) occurred.

[image]

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with Globe are well known, please follow e.g. http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9818